# for loop date don't want to include current date

Tags: c#, datetime, for-loop

Here is my scenario:

1. Given `startDate = 1/7/2012` and `endDate = 9/7/2012`
2. Database contains: `4/7/2012` and `5/7/2012`
3. Read and return dates on an interval which are not included in the database

Expected result (DD/MM/YYYY):

```
1/7/2012
2/7/2012
3/7/2012
6/7/2012
7/7/2012
8/7/2012
9/7/2012
```

Below is the code I am working with:

```
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2012, 7, 1, 0, 0, 0);
DateTime endDate = new DateTime(2012, 7, 9, 0, 0, 0);
int interval = 1;

MySqlConnection connDate = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
MySqlCommand cmdDate = connDate.CreateCommand();

cmdDate.Parameters.Add("username", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
cmdDate.Parameters["username"].Value = Session["username"].ToString();

cmdDate.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM report WHERE username = @username";

connDate.Open();

MySqlDataReader drDate = cmdDate.ExecuteReader();
this.Label1.Text = "";

for (DateTime dateTime = startDate; dateTime < endDate; dateTime += TimeSpan.FromDays(interval))
{
    //start from here, i don't know exactly what i am doing.
    DateTime reportDate = Convert.ToDateTime(null);
    while (drDate.Read())
    {
        reportDate = Convert.ToDateTime(drDate["reportDate"].ToString());
    }

    if (Convert.ToDateTime(drDate["reportDate"].ToString()).ToShortDateString() != reportDate.ToShortDateString())
    {
        this.Label1.Text += dateTime.ToString() + "</br>";
    }
}
connDate.Close();
```

The question is, the code above displays all the dates from 1 to 9 of July 2012. Instead, I would like it to display every date except the 4th and 5th of July which are already included in the database.

Comment: the code i posted it displays all the date include 4 and 5 July 2012(which in database), i wanted to by pass the date which already in the database :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create an enumerable or list of dates you want to exclude (dates from database). Then you will want to execute your loop to get all dates in the range you specify. Inside that loop, you will want to add all dates that are not contained in your enumerable to the label.

```
IList<DateTime> exclusionDates = new List<DateTime>();

while (drDates.read())
{
    exclusionDates.Add(Convert.ToDateTime(drDates["reportDate"].ToString()));
}

for (DateTime dateTime = startDate; dateTime < endDate; dateTime += TimeSpan.FromDays(interval))
{
    if (!exclusionDates.Contains(dateTime))
    {
        this.Label1.Text += dateTime.ToString() + "</br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: The `.ToString` in the `Convert.ToDateTime` isn't necessary.

Comment: Also, just as a side note, running through your while(drDates.Read()) loop and assigning the value to a variable, then using that value outside of this loop will result in you always using the last entry retrieved through the data reader. This is why I added to a list that was declared outside the scope of the loop and probably why you never compared to the earlier values in the database. If you set a breakpoint on your if statement, you should see that the reportDate value is always the same...

Comment: how can i do something like this? `if (!Convert.ToDateTime(exclusionDates).ToShortDateString().Contains(Convert.ToDateTime(dateTime).ToShortDateString()))` . i want to compare the Date only.

Comment: One more thing, you should put your while(drDates.Read()) outside of the containing for loop to prevent unnecessary calls to the database. This will impact performance. For performance reasons, I'd also probably limit the sql statement to retrieving values between your start date and end date. (i.e. `"SELECT * FROM report WHERE username = @username AND (reportDate >= @startDate AND reportDate <= @endDate)"`) just don't forget to declare the startDate and endDate parameters...

Comment: yes, thx for the advice, i already move the `while()` to the outside of for-loop. how can i compare Date only? Convert ToShortDateString seems give me an error here

Comment: @melvintcs, if you want to compare the Date only, then I'd change exclusionDates to IList<string> and add like so: `exclusionDates.Add(Convert.ToDateTime(drDates["reportDate"].ToString()).ToShortDateString())` then in your compare, say `if (!exclusionDates.Contains(dateTime.ToShortDateString()))`

Comment: actually is ` exclusionDates.Add(Convert.ToDateTime(drDate["reportDate"].ToString()).ToShortDateString().ToString());` you forget to convert back to string. Brilliant idea by the way! thousand thx! :D

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you want to do? Specifically which dates from the example you provided that you want to add?

Answer (score 3):

Given `startDate`, `endDate`, and a daily interval:

```
// Assumes IEnumerable<DateTime> dbDates;
var remaining =
    Enumerable.Range(0, Int32.MaxValue)
              .Select(day => startDate.AddDays(day))
              .Where(d => d <= endDate)
              .Except(dbDates);
```

Or perhaps the more familiar iterative approach:

```
// Given: HashSet<DateTime> except = new HashSet<DateTime>(dbDates);
for (DateTime date = startDate;
     date <= endDate;
     date = date.AddDays(1))
{
    if (except.Contains(date)) continue;

    // We now have 'date' which is unused in the db
}
```

And for help with retrieval from the database, you can use the `GetDateTime` overload:

```
// List<DateTime> is another option if you care about order
var dbDates = new HashSet<DateTime>();
while (drDate.Read())
{
    dbDates.Add(drDate.GetDateTime("reportDate"));
}
```

Comment: `Except(dbDates)` catch my eyes, do you mind to explain more? :)

Comment: [Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx) removes values from an `IEnumerable` based on another `IEnumerable`. For instance `[1,2,3].Except([2])` would return an `IEnumerable` that spits out `1, 3`.

Comment: His dates are d/m/yyyy, not m/d/yyyy.  It looks like you thought it was the latter, since you're adding months.

Comment: melv - look @ http://www.dotnetperls.com/linq, specifically http://www.dotnetperls.com/except  = good explanations

Comment: @TimS.: many thanks for that US-centric catch. I live in a mixed date house, I should know better.

Comment: Thanks for the .Except info. I'll have to make more use of that one!

Comment: Thanks, this is something new for me :)